# Iterate over and call blocks (in NSMutableArray)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to add blocks to an NSMutableArray, and iterate over the array and call the blocks.

I have:

```
-(void)doSomethingAsyncWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completion {
  if (alreadyDoingSomething) {
     // Only add block, will be called after doSomethingAsync has finished
     [self.completionHandlers addObject: [completion copy]];
  } else {
     // Add block, then doSomethingAsync
     [self.completionHandlers addObject: [completion copy]];
     [self doSomethingAsync];
  }
}
```

Example of use:

```
[self doSomethingAsyncWithCompletionHandler:
   [self doStuff];
}];

[self doSomethingAsyncWithCompletionHandler:
   [self doMoreStuff];
}];
```

So, given that above is a correct way of doing it (I'm not sure if adding the blocks to the array is ok like that), what I want in doSomethingAsync is:

```
-(void)doSomethingAsync {
   // Do stuff async, e.g. get application token.
   // When done:
   //for (block in self.completionhandlers) {
   //    //call block
   //    block();
   //}
}
```

How do I iterate over and call the blocks?

**UPDATE**:
The specific problem that I want to tackle with the above, is:
I have a singleton LoginManager class, that takes care of showing a login screen (UIAlertView) when the user or the system attempts to do something that needs authentication. The system may, theoretically, call a method that needs authentication, and then call another method that also needs authentication before the user had the chance to finish logging in.

To make sure both the first and the second action eventually get called, I try and keep them in an array as blocks, so that they all can be called once the user has finished logging in.

I use it like this:

```
-(void)syncRoutesInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context onSuccess:(void(^)())successCompletionHandler onError:(void(^)())errorCompletionHandler {
    if (![[Settings applicationToken] length]) {
        [[LoginManager sharedManager] showLoginViewOnSuccess:^{
            [self syncRoutesInManagedObjectContext:context onSuccess:successCompletionHandler onError:errorCompletionHandler];
        }];
    } else if (![[Settings sessionToken] length]) {
        [[ARAPIConnectionManager sharedManager] getSessionTokenWithCompletionHandler:^{
            [self syncRoutesInManagedObjectContext:context onSuccess:successCompletionHandler onError:errorCompletionHandler];
        }];
    } else {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/routes.json", API_ROOT_URL, [Settings sessionToken]]];
        // Get routes
    }
}
```

It's possible that above code (syncRoutes..) caused the login UIAlertView to appear. Then, the user enters credentials and returns. The UIAlertView is dismissed while I try and get the application token from the server. This means that the user can cause another method to fire, like syncDestinations. This other method also cannot do it's stuff until I have the application token and the login process is finished. Hence, I save the method calls in a block and add that block to the array, so it can be called once I have the application token.

Hope it's more clear now what my issue is. Saving blocks and so is new terrain for me so I have no idea if, even though it works perfectly now, this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: I think it would be better to explain _what problem_ you are trying to solve, not _how_ you want to solve it. It's not at all clear what your problem really is.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks for the feedback, I tried to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to solve, but you could use a `dispatch_queue` where you enqueue your handlers. Depending on your problem this can be a concurrent or a serial queue.

Initially, you set the dispatch queue into the suspended mode (`dispatch_suspend()`). You can enqueue blocks to the queue (using `dispatch_async()`, which are not executed until after the queue will be resumed. The actual completion handler of your task will then resume the queue (`dispatch_resume()`) which in turn will execute the handlers.

This is all thread-safe without extra synchronisation.

**Update**

```
// Create the initially suspended handler queue:
dispatch_queue_t handlerQueue = dispatch_create("handlerQueue", NULL);
dispatch_suspend(handlerQueue);

// add blocks:
dispatch_async(handlerQueue, ^{
    ...
});
dispatch_async(handlerQueue, ^{
    ...
});


// Start your asynchronous task whose completion handler 
// resumes the handler queue
[self taskWithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_resume(self.handlerQueue);
}];
```

This is a very simplified approach. It gets more challenging when you want to pass a result from the task's completion handler to the blocks enqueued in the handler queue, want to implement cancellation, and want to pass "exceptions".

Considering these requirements, your problem can be solved nicely, too, with using "promises" or "futures".  (You might search for [RXPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise) on git hub, which is one implementation of a promise in Objective-C (where I'm the author). There are a few other implementations, too, and there are even more elegant implementations in Swift.)

Comment: Looks interesting, will look into that. Is there any reason why this approach is better than storing the blocks in an array?

Comment: @Arjan Well, a dispatch_queue is the natural container for blocks, it's thread-safe and the queue can be used to synchronise access to shared resources, and you can execute the blocks either serially or concurrent, and it's more light-weight than even a NSArray, and more ;)  Consider also that you need to make the other approach thread.safe as well - that is, the creation of the NSArray and every access, too. So you would use GCD anyway.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, see my [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/iDKcEiZE). But how do I keep a reference to this queue? Can I keep a pointer?

And could you put me a bit in the right direction about making my existing code thread safe? I mean, The class is a singleton created with dispatch_once, and I only access / change the NSMutableArray from within the singleton class. Wouldn't that mean I don't have to use GCD?

Answer (score 0):

Think I found it. This seems to be working:

```
for (void (^completionHandler)() in self.completionHandlers) {
   completionHandler();
}
[self.completionHandlers removeAllObjects];
```

If someone has something to say about this code in terms of leaks or so, please do!

Comment: I would check block on nil when adding it to the array. Also why you destroy array at the end? You can just call 'removeAllObjects'. Otherwise you must create it each time before adding in it somethig.